# PhpUnit testing method with that have variable argument array

Tags: php, unit-testing, mocking, phpunit

My scenario is that I am testing a method which calls another method from a library that takes an array with two keys `['id'=>123, 'timestamp'=>microtime()]`. I can put this microtime as an argument to the method I am testing but is there a way that I could make this test so that I test all keys except certain keys are equal for the method being called.

```
     $this->foobarLibary->expects($this->once())
                ->method('saveItem')
                ->with(['id'=>1, 'timestamp'=>microtime()])
                ->willReturn(200);

       $res =  $this->sut->sutMethodThatCallsFoobarSaveItem();

       $this->assertTrue($res);
```

I get complain that `timestamp` keys are not equal and which is true because microtime is different .

This test fails now because time cannot be equal. Is there a workaround?

Comment: Show what function is tested, maybe this help. The test itself is not too much.

Comment: `sutMethodThatCallsFoobarSaveItem` is the function being tested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Symfony (or you can use the [phpunit-bridge](https://github.com/symfony/phpunit-bridge)) I suggest you to take a look at the [ClockMock feature](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/phpunit_bridge.html#clock-mocking):

> The [ClockMock](http://api.symfony.com/4.0/Symfony/Bridge/PhpUnit/ClockMock.html) class provided by this bridge allows you to mock
>   the PHP's built-in time functions `time()`, `microtime()`, `sleep()`
>   and `usleep()`.

You can read [here](http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-8-clock-mocking-and-time-sensitive-tests#alternative-ways-to-enable-the-clock-mocking) about use without the Symfony Framework

hope this help

Comment: Hi, thank you for your comment on this. I am not using symfony  framework here. But this `phpunit-bridge` looks promising. I will take a look at this.